# railsでページ読み込み時に毎回スクリプトを実行したい

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

文字のカウント数を表示するcoffescriptのプログラムなのですが、
ブラウザの再読込を行なった際にしか実行されません。

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
    thisValueLength = $('#comment').val().length;
    $('#count').html(thisValueLength);
```

ページ遷移時等に毎回実行する方法はないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page:load` イベントが発火していないので、Rails 5 (Turbolinks 5) を利用しているのだと思います。このバージョンでは、`turbolinks:load` を利用する必要があります。

Comment: 使用しているRailsは4.2.0でしたが、`turbolinks:load`で上手く行きました。ありがとうございます。